# How can I link a JavaScript command to a form button in php? (<div>)

Tags: javascript, php

I have a footer banner on a website that I manage and when I click hide or hide forever it called the following javascript to hide or hide forever the banner:

```
/**
 * Main JS File
 *
 * @author Your Inspiration Themes
 * @package YITH Footer Banner
 * @version 1.0.3
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if($.cookie(templateDir) == '1') {
        $(".fbanner").hide();
    }
    $("#showhidefbanner a").on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.fbanner').hide();
    });
     $("#showhideforever").on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".fbanner").hide();
        $.cookie(templateDir, '1',{ expires: 365, path: '/' });
    });
});
```

Until here everything ok.
The problem is that when someone send the form the banner the banner keeps appearing. Therefore I want to called this javascript to never show this banner again. Here is my php code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Footer Banner page
 *
 * @author Your Inspiration Themes
 * @package YITH Footer Banner
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
;?>
<!-- YITH-FOOTER-BANNER -->
<div class="fbanner">
    <div id="fbannercont" class="group">
        <div id="fbannerlogo">
            <?php if (get_option('yith_fbanner_link')):?><a href="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_link');?>" title="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_message');?>"><?php endif;?>
                <img src="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_image');?>" alt="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_message');?>"/>
            <?php if (get_option('yith_fbanner_link')):?></a><?php endif;?>
        </div>
        <ul id="fbannermess">
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <?php if (get_option('yith_fbanner_link')):?><a href="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_link');?>" title="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_message');?>"><?php endif;?>
                        <?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_message');?>
                    <?php if (get_option('yith_fbanner_link')):?></a><?php endif;?>
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>
                    <?php if (get_option('yith_fbanner_link')):?><a href="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_link');?>" title="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_message');?>"><?php endif;?>
                        <?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_sub_message');?>
                    <?php if (get_option('yith_fbanner_link')):?></a><?php endif;?>
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="fbannernews">
            <?php if ( get_option('yith_fbanner_enable_newsletter_form') == true ): ?>
                <form method="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_method') ?>" action="<?php echo _e (get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_action') ,'yit');?>" class="fbannernewsletter">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="147265" />
                <input type="hidden" name="encoding" value="" />                    
<fieldset>
                            <?php if(get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_name_label')){?>
                                <ul class="newsfields">
                                    <li class="newstop">
                                        <input type="text" name="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_name_name') ?>" id="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_name_name') ?>" class="name-field text-field" placeholder="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_name_label') ?>" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="newsbottom">
                                        <input type="text" name="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_email_name') ?>" id="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_email_name') ?>" class="email-field text-field" placeholder="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_email_label') ?>" />
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_submit_label') ?>" class="submit-field newssubmit" />
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <input type="text" name="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_email_name') ?>" id="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_email_name') ?>" class="email-field text-field" placeholder="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_email_label') ?>" />
                            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_submit_label') ?>" class="submit-field" />
                        <?php };?>
                            <?php $hiddenfields = get_option('yith_fbanner_newsletter_hidden_fields');
                                if ($hiddenfields) :
                                $result = explode('&',$hiddenfields);
                                foreach ($result as $hivalue ) :
                                $formvalue = explode('=',$hivalue);?>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $formvalue[0] ?>" name="<?php echo $formvalue[0] ?>" value="<?php echo $formvalue[1] ?>" />
                                <?php endforeach; endif;?>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- fbannercont -->

    <ul class="hiderzone">
        <li>
            <div id="showhideforever">
                <a href="#" title="<?php _e( get_option('yith_fbanner_hide_forever_message') ,'yit');?>">
                    <?php echo _e( get_option('yith_fbanner_hide_forever_message') ,'yit');?>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="showhidefbanner">
                <a href="#" title="<?php _e( get_option('yith_fbanner_hide_message') ,'yit');?>">
                    <?php _e( get_option('yith_fbanner_hide_message') ,'yit');?>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- fbanner -->
<!-- YITH-FOOTER-BANNER -->
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't hide things "forever", but you can hide it for say... 50-100 years in the future. I doubt they'll live that long ;)

Comment: yes I know. Is set for 365 days. But I cannot link with the form button.

Comment: Do you mean that the element is re-appearing after you reload the page?  If that's the case then you'd need to either not reload the page (interact with the server via AJAX instead) or include in the form post some indication that the server-side code could use to conditionally render different output.

Comment: Btw, the website: http://gold-prediction.com . I u want to take a look

Comment: I mean to the same action when I click submit as when I click "hide forever"

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a js function and call the function after send your form:

```
<script>    
function showHideBannerFix() {
    $(".fbanner").hide();
    $.cookie(templateDir, '1',{ expires: 365, path: '/' });
}
</script>
```

And in your php that the form was submited to:

```
echo '<script>showHideBannerFix();</script>';
```

I didn't test it, but i think its right.

Comment: where should I create this function? In the main java file?